# How can I determine the number of worksheet cells I have passed to a VBA function?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, user-defined-functions

My user-defined function takes two ranges as parameters. I need to know how big the ranges are (number of rows). Ubound(Ti) doesn't work.

```
Function Andrade(M As Variant, Ti As Variant) As Variant

Dim Mu(1 To 7) '------------> "7" needs to be the number of elements in M
Dim T(1 To 7)  '------------> ditto

For j = 1 To 7
    Mu(j) = Log(M(j))
    T(j) = 1 / Ti(j)
Next j

' Code here varies depending whether the function is passed
' single values for M and Ti or multiple values (arrays)

End Function``
```

Comment: What do you try accomplishing? How (exactly) do you call the function in discussion? Shouldn't the parameters be `Range` instead of `Variant`? If so, your function is wrong. A range contains rows and columns. If you use a range in one column, you should use `Log(M(j, 1))` instead of `Log(M(j))` and in case of row ranges you should use `Log(M(1, j))`. Then, how do you want returning the two 1D arrays. Your function does not explicitly return anything. In case of ranges you should use `Ti.Rows.Count`. Or `Ti.Columns.Count` according to the way of building the range.

Comment: Thanks for the questions. What I am doing is making a variant of the LINEST worksheet function. My UDF, ANDRADE(m,Ti) is taking the range of m values and Ti values, manipulating them so they become the objects of a linear equation, and then applying rtnArray = WORKSHEETFUNCTION.LineEst(Mu,T). rtnArray then contains the coefficients that LINEST computed. But if ANDRADE only receives single values for m and Ti I need to use different code to process it. In addition, I have to do some error trapping to be sure that both Mu and T contain the same number of values.

Comment: FaneDunru: THANK YOU - changing the parameter to Range from Variant solved my problem.

Comment: You did not answer my clarification questionregarding the real ranges you use. I asked How do you call the function? If you intend to call it with a range on a column ("A2:A20") or a row ("A2:R2") it is a little different to obtain what you need. In principle, you can make a 2D array from a range, simple using `arr = M.Value`. Then use `Ubound(arr)` for rows and `Ubound(arr, 2)` for rows...

Comment: Perfect! If I type =ANDRADE(A1:A5,C3:G3) I now see how to figure out the shape and dimensions of the function parameters. Thanks again.

Comment: Please read `Ubound(arr, 2)` for **columns**, not for rows, as I wrote by mistake...:)